# Express typescript passing data between middleware

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, middleware

I'm making my first express app with Typescript.

I tried to pass data between middleware as i did in javascript (express app)

in my javascript app it was very fine to passing data between

what am i doing wrong here? where am i missing

```
interface IUserType extends Request {
  user: {
    id: string;
    name: string;
  };
}

const middleWare = (req: IUserType, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  req.user = {
    id: "user_id",
    name: "John Doe",
  };
  return next();
};


const getUser = (req: IUserType, res: Response) => {
  console.log(req.user, "User Data");
  return res.status(200).json({ user: req.user });
};

router.route("/user").get(middleWare, getUser);
```

but i got these types error in typescript

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(...handlers: RequestHandler<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs>[]): IRoute', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(req: MyProfileRequest, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestHandler<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs>'.
      Types of parameters 'req' and 'req' are incompatible.
        Property 'user' is missing in type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs>' but required in type 'MyProfileRequest'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(...handlers: RequestHandlerParams<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs>[]): IRoute', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(req: MyProfileRequest, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestHandlerParams<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs>'.
      Type '(req: MyProfileRequest, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => void' is not assignable to type 'RequestHandler<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs>'.ts(2769)
```

my code in codesandbox :[Code Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-dew-ki8390?file=/src/routes/user.ts)

I was expecting no types error because i specified what my types would be

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to use [TypeScript declaration files](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/type-declarations.html#:%7E:text=TypeScript%20includes%20declaration%20files%20for,Object%20%2C%20and%20their%20associated%20types.) to augment the `Express` namespace. At the root of your project (where your **index.ts** lives), create a file called **decs.d.ts** and add this:

```
type User = {
    id: string;
    name: string;
};

declare namespace Express {
    interface Request {
        user?: User;
    }
}
```

Then, in your **index.ts** you can use it as you normally would:

```
import express from 'express';
import type { Request, Response, NextFunction, RequestHandler } from 'express';

const app = express();

const middleware = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    req.user = {
        id: 'user_id',
        name: 'John Doe',
    };

    return next();
};

const getUser: RequestHandler = (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.user, 'User Data');
    return res.status(200).json({ user: req.user });
};

app.get('/foo', middleware, getUser);
```

No more type errors!

Comment: Tanks `decs.d.ts` file works well.
I got one more silly question 
if i make  *.d.ts files should i let my tsconfig.json knows i have new *.d.ts file?

Comment: @Cono You shouldn't have to if the `decs.d.ts` is at the root of your project, but if you wanted it to live in a different folder you'd have to add it under `compilerOptions.typeRoots` in an array.